# Form API-built form only emails Array, not the form results

Tags: 6, forms, emails

I am having a special moment here:
I need to send an email with form results. These form results are in two fieldsets. This should be the easiest part of building this, but I'm having a brain freeze. How can I use a foreach loop or something similar to print my form results to the email being sent? Here's what I wrote, which just says 1 instead of the full results array:

```
     $uppgifter = $form_state['values']['dina_uppgifter'];
     foreach($uppgifter as $key=>$value) {
        if ($value > 0) {
            $params['message'][] .= "<p><strong>" . $key . ": </strong>" . $value . "</p> <br />";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is probably the problem:

```
$params['message'][] .= ...
```

If `$params['message']` is a string then you want to be concatenating directly to that string like this:

```
$params['message'] .= ...
```

When you put empty square brackets `[]` on the end of a variable PHP treats that variable as an array and essentially pushes whatever's after the `=` sign on to the array.

The way you're doing it (with a string concatenation of `.=`) I'm not actually sure what the logic flow would be but it wouldn't be pretty...I'm surprised you don't get a fatal error for this :)

Comment: Found that out the hard way :p brackets are gone but still not getting the right info.... gotta think about how exactly to write this.... thanks for your input!